# SDWebImage - Ignores set value of MaxCacheSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage, image-caching

I'm working on an iOS app and have just started implementing the amazing cache plugin SDWebImage. The thing I'm stuck at now is that I'm trying to implement a cache with a "limited size" of 200 or 500 MB and I've found the function setMaxCacheSize and I'm entering the descried number. When I print the value with NSLog in the app and simulator it shows correctly BUT the thing is that my cache still can go beyond this size... It's like the code is ignoring the max size and just keeps adding files without removing to make space..?

Is it something that I'm missing? Something that needs to be called on to make it autoClean memory when the limit is exceeded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

you could have a look at this property.

/**
 * Decompressing images that are downloaded and cached can improve performance but can consume lot of memory.
 * Defaults to YES. Set this to NO if you are experiencing a crash due to excessive memory consumption.
 */
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldDecompressImages;

Comment: Please provide source

Comment: It's showed in file named 'SDImageCache.h'.line 40.

Comment: Use like this:`[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];`
   `[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];`